# Run pipeline/job from other pipeline/job in GCP datafusion / CDAP

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

Run pipeline/job from other pipeline/job in GCP  datafusion / CDAP. Talend have the stage "tRunJob" to run the job within other job. Looking at same type of the feature in Data fusion or CDAP open source platform.

Answer (score 1):

Manish: You can trigger a pipeline based on success/failure or just run of another pipeline. You can read more about triggers here - [Triggers in CDAP](https://medium.com/cdapio/event-based-triggers-for-cdap-pipelines-6f1c4b20adc3)